# mysql update with subquery 2 level deep

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery

Thanks for taking a look at this question. I'm kind of lost and hope someone can help me. Below is a update query i would like to run. 
This query now returns an error:

#### 1054 - Unknown column 'spi.et_cross_rank' in 'where clause'

Some background:
from table: **tmp_ranking_tbl** 
I would like to get the **nth**(spi.et_return_rank) record 
for a group with value **x** (spi.et_cross_rank)

```
SET @rownum=0;      
    
UPDATE STRToer_Poule_indeling spi
SET spi.team_id = (SELECT R.team_poule_id 
  FROM (SELECT  @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum, trt.team_poule_id 
       FROM tmp_ranking_tbl  trt
       WHERE trt.overal_rank = spi.et_cross_rank 
       ORDER BY trt.punten DESC, (trt.goals_voor - trt.goals_tegen) DESC, trt.goals_voor DESC) R
  WHERE R.rownum = spi.et_return_rank)
WHERE spi.et_ronde = v_et_ronde
AND spi.poule_id IN (SELECT row_id FROM STRToer_Poules WHERE toernooi_onderdeel_id=v_onderdeel_id) ;
```

Data in tmp_ranking_tbl  looks like:

```
team_poule_id | punten | goals_voor | goals_tegen | overal_rank
65            | 6      | 10         | 10          | 2 
69            | 6      | 9          | 10          | 2
75            | 7      | 11         | 4           | 2
84            | 6      | 6          | 8           | 2
112           | 5      | 7          | 7           | 2
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Update after question in comment about the goal, i'll try to keep it short. :-)
This query is used on a website to keep scores of a tournament. Sometimes you have an odd number of teams going to the next round. At that point I want to select the best number 3(spi.et_cross_rank) team across poules. This is setting saved in the STRToer_Poule_indeling with what rank per poule and the 1st, 2nd or nth team(spi.et_return_rank). The table tmp_ranking_tbl is filled with all rank 3 teams across the poules. When this if filled I would like the 1st or 2nd, depedining on the setting in STRToer_Poule_indeling, record to return.

Subset of structure the STRToer_Poule_indeling table

```
row_id | team_id | et_ronde | et_cross_rank | et_return_rank
1      | null    | 1        | 3             | 1
```

Comment: Perhaps JOIN instead of subquery update.

Comment: thanks, do you know an example. haven't found a way to do this with a join. (might be that i'm looking at it to long).<br /> (added) reason why i don't know how to use a join is the rownum functionality. What the nth record of the record set and limit doens't allow variables in it's statement

Answer (score 0):

Just check if you have a column named ***et_cross_rank*** on your table ***STRToer_Poule_indeling***

The problem seems to be that SQL can't find that column on your table.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes, that's there. What I have found is dat subqueries can only use the value of their direct parent and not of any higher in the "tree". Meaning this query won't work. However i haven't found a way to work around this.

Comment: What is your goal with that update query? Show me the rest of the tables so I can help you better.

However, if it is a scope problem, you could try to add the table "STRToer_Poule_indeling" on your inner SELECT like this:


FROM tmp_ranking_tbl  trt, STRToer_Poule_indeling spi
WHERE trt.overal_rank = spi.et_cross_rank

Comment: updated above with more details. For your query, there is no relation between tmp_ranking_tbl and STRToer_poule_indeling so don't know how to join